# Deleting URL Forwarding - Freenom

Tags: web, url, redirect

accidentally I made url forward in freenom. Now I can't disable it. It's saying "leave blank to disable" but when I leave it blank, there's error that I have to specify URL or nameserver. Any help? Tried looking on google but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found out how to do it. I noticed that it deleted nameservers for Cloudflare. I just had to re-enter them and it's fixed now.

Comment: This is confirmed working. If using freenom's nameserver just set it again. This causes URL Forward values to reset. Looks site developer was sleeping when he implemented this feature. I hope he wakes up soon. Site is generally buggy.